# How to extract tabular data from a website using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-extraction

I am trying to extract the data from the webpage 
https://www.geojit.com/other-market/world-indices 
and many others similar to this.

I need to get the tabular data of the website (INDEX,NAME,COUNTRY,CLOSE,PREV.CLOSE,NET CHANGE,CHANGE (%),LAST UPDATED DATE & TIME). would be great if you can share the R code for this or any help would be welcome.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)   
google <- html("https://www.geojit.com/other-market/world-indices")    
google %>%    
html_nodes()
```

Comment: See if my answer works for you.

Comment: Yes it does Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(rvest)
my_tbl <- read_html("https://www.geojit.com/other-market/world-indices") %>%    
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id=\"aboutContent\"]/div[2]/table") %>%
  html_table(header = TRUE) %>%
  `[[`(1)
```